# Accessing Fragment's views after inflating

Tags: android, android-fragments, nullpointerexception, android-inflate

### **What I need to achieve**

A screen displaying a `ListView`, which can be replaced by an error screen in case of problems  (missing connection, server unavailable and the like).
I need to be able to switch (programmatically) back and forth between these two screens.

### **Requirements**

The main screen must be a Fragment.
This is because my application is composed of several sections, each one accessible from the navigation drawer.

### **What I have done so far**

The main fragment class is named `AllQueuesFragment`: its XML layout consists of a `FrameLayout`, which I use in combination with the `FragmentManager` to switch between `ErrorFragment` (containing the error message) and `QueuesViewFragment` (containing the `ListView`).

```
public class AllQueuesFragment extends Fragment
{   
    public AllQueuesFragment()
    {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart()
    {
        super.onStart();

        // Show the right fragment based on connectivity status
        checkConnection();
    }

    public void checkConnection()
    {
        final NetworkManager netManager = NetworkManager.getInstance(this.getActivity());

        if (netManager.isConnected())
            showQueues();
        else
            showNoConnection();     
    }

    public void showNoConnection()
    {
        ErrorFragment fragNoConnection = new ErrorFragment();
        displayFragment(fragNoConnection);

        fragNoConnection.setTitle(R.string.text_no_connection);
        fragNoConnection.setIcon(R.drawable.thatfeel);
        fragNoConnection.setLoaderVisibility(false);        
    }

    public void showQueues()
    {
        QueuesViewFragment fragQueuesView = new QueuesViewFragment();
        displayFragment(fragQueuesView);
    }   

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        // Inflate the view
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_allqueues, container, false);

        return rootView;
    }

    // Displays a new fragment
    public void displayFragment(Fragment fragment)
    {       
        if (fragment != null) 
        {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();
        } 
    }                                       
}
```

The error screen is the following:

```
public class ErrorFragment extends Fragment 
{   
    private TextView textTitle;

    public ErrorFragment()
    {       
        super();
    }   

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        // Inflate the view
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_error, container, false);

        // Get the widgets
        textTitle = (TextView)rootView.findViewById( R.id.fragment_error_text );

        return rootView;
    }


    // Set methods
    public void setTitle(int id) { textTitle.setText(id); }
}
```

### **The problem**

The `setTitle()` method gets called before the layout is ready, and as a result, a `NullPointerException` is thrown.

```
class AllQueuesFragment
{
    ....

    public void displayFragment(Fragment fragment)
    {       
        if (fragment != null) 
        {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();
        } 
    }   

    public void showNoConnection()
    {
        ErrorFragment fragNoConnection = new ErrorFragment();
        displayFragment(fragNoConnection);

        // PROBLEM HERE: Before calling setTitle(), I must be sure that ErrorFragment's 
        // layout is inflated!
        fragNoConnection.setTitle(R.string.text_no_connection);
    }

    ....
}

class ErrorFragment
{
    ....
    public void setTitle(String value) { textTitle.setText(value); }
    ....
}
```

I can't call `setTitle()` directly from `ErrorFragment::onCreateView()`, because I don't know beforehand which message I need to show.

How can I ensure that `fragNoConnection` has completed its layouting?
Is there a better way to achieve my goal?

### Unsatisfying workaround

The only workaround I can think of is to use a buffer to defer the actual call:

```
class ErrorFragment
{
    // This string will hold the title until the layout is inflated
    private String titleBuffer;
    private TextView textTitle = null;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        // Inflate the view
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_error, container, false);

        // Get the widgets
        textTitle = (TextView)rootView.findViewById( R.id.fragment_error_text );

        // Do the actual set
        setTitle(titleBuffer);

        return rootView;
    }

    ....

    public void setTitle(String value) 
    { 
            titleBuffer = value;

            // If the layout is not inflated, defer the actual set
            if (textTitle != null)
                    textTitle.setText(titleBuffer); 
    }
    ....
}
```

but I don't like this solution very much (the code above is simplified; `ErrorFragment` has more properties).

Advices?
Thanks in advance

Comment: I would use a ListFragment as well because it works well with list views; this is just a suggestion. As for the solution, I would try the ones suggested below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is exactly the type of thing arguments are supposed to be used for:

```
public void showNoConnection() {
    ErrorFragment fragNoConnection = new ErrorFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    //you can also use putInt here if you'd rather pass a string resource id, along with anything else you can stick into a Bundle
    args.putString("title", "some title");
    fragNoConnection.setArguments(args);
    displayFragment(fragNoConnection);
}
```

Then in `ErrorFragment`

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_error, container, false);

    TextView textTitle = (TextView)rootView.findViewById( R.id.fragment_error_text );
    //now retrieve the argument...
    textTitle.setText(getArguments().getString("title"));

    return rootView;
}
```

The Fragment will even remember it's arguments after an orientation change.

If you feel like being pedantic, you can create a static factory method within `ErrorFragment` that takes the title as an argument and then creates the Fragment and adds the argument, that way you can achieve proper encapsulation :)

Comment: I like this solution! :D
And I think I'm going to be even _more_ pedantic, by implementing the Builder pattern (in the actual code I have several properties).

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a `callback` method in your `ErrorFragment` and when the view is inflated you then call the method in your callback interface in the `onViewCreated` and set the title.

sample:

in **ErroFragment**

```
 public class ErroFragment extends Fragment 
{   
    static interface ErrorDone{
        public void doneInflating();
    }

    private TextView textTitle; 
    private ErrorDone ed;

    public ErroFragment()
    {       
        super();
    }   

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        // Inflate the view
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_error, container, false);

        // Get the widgets
        textTitle = (TextView)rootView.findViewById( R.id.fragment_error_text );

        return rootView;
    }

    // Set methods
    public void setTitle(int id) { textTitle.setText(id); }
    public void setInterFace(ErrorDone er){ this.ed = er; }
}
```

Then you implement the interface in your `AllQueuesFragment`

```
 public class AllQueuesFragment extends Fragment implements ErroFragment.ErrorDone
```

It will generate method `doneInflating`

and you need to set the interface:

```
 public void showNoConnection()
 {
        ErrorFragment fragNoConnection = new ErrorFragment();
        displayFragment(fragNoConnection);
        fragNoConnection.setInterFace(this);      
 }
```

And in the generated method(`doneInflating`) of the `AllQueuesFragment` you then set the title in there:

```
public void doneInflating(){
        fragNoConnection.setTitle(R.string.text_no_connection);
        fragNoConnection.setIcon(R.drawable.thatfeel);
        fragNoConnection.setLoaderVisibility(false); 
}
```

Comment: (1) you'll lose your reference to the interface when the Fragment is recreated on an orientation change. (2) you never call doneInflating() anywhere, making this really useless

Comment: @SamDozor (1) no it wont as long the fragment is recreated and will always initialized that inteface again, (2) I did say call the method in the `onCreateView` see first paraghraph

Comment: Oops yeah you're right re #2, sorry, perhaps you should add that code. Regarding 1, are you suggesting he retry his request, then regenerate the fragment and interface on every orientation change? I don't know about you, but on rotation I like to start exactly where I left off, the FragmentManager will handle recreation of your Fragments for you - but will not magically recreate Strong references you arbitrary added to it during the Fragment's lifetime.

Comment: @SamDozor take note that `AllQueuesFragment` is first recreated and will call `checkConnection` method which by then checks the network connection and if it is not connected then `ErrorFragment` is call again which the interface initialized again.

Comment: Doesn't the activity get destroyed on every rotation change? How could I avoid to rebuild the interface?

Comment: @XDnl yes activity gets destroyed but it will get recreated and will rebuild the interface when the connection is not connected.

Comment: @XDnl the Activity will be destroyed BUT the FragmentManager lives on and maintains a reference to your fragments. Within the onCreate method of your Activity you could use the findFragmentByTag to get a reference to your Fragments. If findFragmentByTag returns null (it always will the first time), create your fragments, otherwise you're off to the races. Here's a related blog: http://benvonhandorf.com/android-fragmentmanager-lifetime-and-memory-leaks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be sure that the `FragmentTransaction` is commited and effective, you can use the `executePendingTransactions` method:

```
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();
    fragmentManager.executePendingTransactions();
```

But,  the right way to do it is to send the title value to the Fragment when instantiating it. This is the default pattern when you create a Fragment from your IDE (eclipse or Android Studio)